# How do I call a .bat file to determine build environment in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, batch-file

In to order to determine the build environment, I have written a .bat that will set the environment variables. How can I call this .bat file before make all?

Comment: Seems like you could do it using the Maven exec plugin but I would bet someone will give you a better answer than that.

Comment: If you run a .bat file from inside Eclipse, any env variables it sets will be lost when it stops and the make begins. Unless ... you can have the make call it somehow.

Comment: I found the answer myself
http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm